# Scraping con Beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Deseo importar un tabla de una página Web, que tiene dos columnas: "FECHA" y "VAL:EUR". La columna  "VAL:EUR" utiliza la coma como separador decimal.
Con el siguiente script consigo la importación y conversión en un dataframe de una sola columna.

```
url = "https://funds.ddns.net/f.php?isin=LU0691314768"
# Obtener el html de la página
html = urlopen(url)
# Crear un objeto Beautiful 
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

# obtener todas las filas de la tabla en forma de lista 
for fila in filas:
    fila_td = fila.find_all('td')

    # Eliminar etiquetas html
str_elementos = str(fila_td)
cleantext = BeautifulSoup(str_cells, "lxml").get_text()

# Crear una lista vacía, extraer el texto entre las etiquetas html de cada fila y agregarlo a la lista creada.
lista_filas = []
for fila in filas:
    elementos = fila.find_all('td')
    str_elementos = str(elementos)
    limpiar = re.compile('<.*?>')
    limpiar1 = (re.sub(limpiar, '',str_elementos))
    lista_filas.append(limpiar1)

# Crear el dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(lista_filas)
```

Me devuelve
    0
0   [FECHA, VL:EUR]
1   [2019-04-23, 157,040000]

Si a continuación intento separar las dos columnas con este script

```
# Dividir la columna "0" en varias columnas en la posición de coma
df1 = df[0].str.split(',', expand=True)
```

Me devuelve tres columnas. La de la fecha, otra con el valor de los enteros y la tercera con el valor de la parte decimal.

¿Existe alguna manera de convertir la coma decimal a punto, antes de realiar la separación comentada?. Agradeceré vuestra ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo que quieres hacer (si no lo entendí mal) se puede lograr sin necesidad de BeautifulSoup e incluso sin necesidad de gestionar la conexión HTTP.

Pandas es una biblioteca muy potente. Es capaz de leer por sí misma desde URLs, no necesariamente desde archivos, y parsear muchos formatos diferentes, entre ellos el HTML en el que buscará elementos `<table>` y extraerá las filas y columnas. Además, mediante los parámetros apropiados puedes especificarle que la coma se está usando como separador de decimales.

En una sola línea, se hace todo:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_html(url, header=0, thousands="", decimal="," )[0]
```

El `[0]` del final es porque `pd.read_html()` te devuelve una lista con todas las tablas que haya encontrado en el HTML. En este caso nos quedamos con la primera.

Resultado:

```
>>> print(df.head())
        FECHA  VL:EUR
0  2019-04-23  157.04
1  2019-04-18  157.46
2  2019-04-17  157.56
3  2019-04-16  157.54
4  2019-04-15  157.39
```

**Bonus**

Puedes pedirle de paso que te trate la columna "FECHA" como `datetime` y que la use como índice. Eso te permitiría después hacer cosas como agrupar por meses, día de la semana, etc.

```
>>> df=pd.read_html(url, header=0, thousands="", decimal=",",
                    parse_dates=True, index="FECHA")[0]
>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 1886 entries, 2019-04-23 to 2011-10-13
Data columns (total 1 columns):
VL:EUR    1886 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 29.5 KB

>>> print(df.groupby(by=df.index.month).mean())
           VL:EUR
FECHA            
1      143.518256
2      144.263750
3      144.455380
4      143.426234
5      143.567929
6      144.606294
7      144.150452
8      146.183377
9      146.198255
10     140.491953
11     140.100364
12     141.379172
```

Comment: Esto es ilusionante. Cada día aprendo algo nuevo. Tu respuesta es muy pedagógica. Te quedo muy agradecido.